# Undefined variable in view if passing from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Easypost.com api, getting rates in controller and passing variable thru compact to the view.

```
return view ('pages.rates', compact('shipment'));
```

In view I am doing foreach to show all available shipping methods.
I have calculator form on the same view like results are.
But if the user will come on the page for the first time, variable $shipment is not set yet and getting error: undefined variable.
I tried to make an condition like:

```
@if (isset($shipment)
   @foreach $shipment->rates as $rate
   //rest of code (there are some ifs as well)
   @endforeach
@else
No rates found
@endif
```

but its giving me the same error.
Can you help me how to check if variable passed to the view is set and if not I need to have an option to show something like: No rates found.
I also tried @isset, but its the same.
Thanks

Comment: `@if (isset($shipment)` is missing a closing `)`. Did you `dd($shipment);` in your controller to check if it's set?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$shipment` is set and contain rates

```
    @forelse ($shipment->rates as $rate)
        //rest of code (there are some ifs as well)
    @empty
        No rates found
    @endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I am using session, so I created if statement in the function in the controller:

```
 if (session()->missing('weight')) {     
      
        Session::put('from_address_street1', 'Street');
        Session::put('from_address_city', 'Atlanta');
        Session::put('from_address_state', 'GA');
        Session::put('from_address_zip', '30092');
        Session::put('from_address_country', 'US');
        Session::put('weight', '4');
    }
```

So I am checking if weight exists in session and if not, its giving default value to the calculator if the session is not set up yet.
This solved my problem. Thank you